How to send html traffic from a html file to a Load Balancer in AWS?
I made an architecture in AWS like this :
2 AZ, each AZ has one public subnet and 3 private ones.
The three subnets are for: web servers (html and css files),app servers (node.js file) and a database.
I made load balancers and auto scaling.
The server works fine except that i have a page that needs to send data (forum) to the node.js server to put it in the database,
so i put it like this my html file:
< form action="http:///submit" method="post"> and
this is how my server app.js is accepting the data:     app.post('/submit', (req, res) => (on port 3000)
in the SG of the LB i made the traffic type http with the source being the web servers' SG
my problem is when i try to submit the forum it always say :
LB DNS Name took too long to respond
Did i do something wrong ?
I tried changing the inbound and outbound rules but it didn't work.
I'm thinking maybe this is wrong:  form action="http:///submit" method="post"...

The URL should either be absolute or relative. In your case, you have given the protocol and /submit. If the domain name and protocol remains same, set the action to action=/submit. Since you want this submit request to go to nodejs, create a higher priority listener rule on your ALB (I am assuming that you are using an application load balancer) to eoute the path /submit to the target group of nodeJs

Thanks! that actually made the traffic go to the app servers .

Hi, so your solution worked and the load balancer is now recognized but i'm stuck with 504 Gateway Timeout now.
i don't know why but the data won't transfer.
the nginx server isn't getting any connection.
Does anyone know why ?

@AdamZ if you are getting 504 from ALB, it means that the request or connection attempted timeout occurred. Priliminary check in this will be to make sure that the Security Group of ALB and Target is open in the respective direction (i.e Egress for ALB and Ingress for Target). If this is all through, check whether nginx is listening on the port by using netstat -an | grep "LISTEN" | grep ":3000". Another test on nginx instance will be to use curl localhost:3000 to test by connecting to itself

I fixed the problem! Actually it was in the nginx.conf file
location /submit {
proxy_pass http://DNS-NAME:80;
was the problem
previously it was proxy_pass http://DNS-NAME:3000;
i found this very helpful page and fixed the problem.
Thank you harold you were a great help and your solution fixed my problem.
